How to use label_smooth in Tensorflow object detection API?
How to use label_smooth in Tensorflow object detection API when I train Faster rcnn?
I try to put
label_smoothing = 0.1
factor = tf.constant(label_smoothing)
target_tensor *= (1 - factor)
target_tensor += (factor / target_tensor.shape[2].value)
in losses.py class WeightedSoftmaxClassificationLoss(Loss):
But it has no effect. Even deleting the entire class will not affect the training.
Where should I put the loss?
Thanks
